# Spring boot cache memory usage

Tags: java, maven, caching, spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm using the default caching methods provided by spring boot. I have not configured any cache manager. I am simply using `@Cacheable`, `@CacheEvict` annotations and nothing else.

- According to spring:
[#cache-strategies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-strategies)

```
Just like other services in the Spring Framework, the caching service is an abstraction 
(not a cache implementation) and requires the use of an actual storage to store the 
cache data - that is, the abstraction frees the developer from having to write the 
caching logic but does not provide the actual stores. This abstraction is materialized 
by the org.springframework.cache.Cache and org.springframework.cache.CacheManager 
interfaces.
```

It also says:
[#boot-features-caching-provider-simple](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-simple)

```
If none of the other providers can be found, a simple implementation using a 
ConcurrentHashMap as cache store is configured.
```

My question is:
 - What is the actual memory used by spring boot simple cache?
 - Does it obey JAVA_OPTS/CATALINA_OPTS memory limits?

Comment: How does JAVA_OPTS/CATALINA_OPTS relate to your cache?

Comment: With regard to memory configurations.
`- Does it obey JAVA_OPTS/CATALINA_OPTS memory limits?`

Comment: How did you use these EV in the configuration?

Comment: These are options to configure heap memory. Are you trying to put your cache in heap? If yes, I don't think that is a good idea. You would ideally want to maintain in memory cache or disk based cache depending on your requirement.

Comment: @JosimarLopes Did you get any solution to check caching memory usage ?